# Change default OS Setting linux Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: dual-boot

Well i want to know how can i change my default OS boot system Setting. I installed ubuntu with Window 7.My default OS is Ubuntu 11.4. Please tell me step by step I am new in Linux World

Comment: What default setting?, you installed Ubuntu with Wubi?, you want to Make Ubuntu the default OS?.. i'm not sure what you asked here.

Answer (score 7):

Just click [this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/startupmanager). The package "startupmanager" will be installed, and then you will be able to configure default OS boot system from the "system" menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm asuming you want to dual boot and have ubuntu on its own partition and windows on the other . try looking at this site it gives step by step guide how to do exzactly that!  *http://www.ubuntugeek.com/step-by-step-guide-installing-ubuntu-11-04-natty-on-a-windows-7-dual-booting.html* Hope this helps!

Beware you must back up any data that you wish to keep or it will be lost.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...